# How to get Input Type file on ajax submit of form- Trying to get url of the uploaded file in IE 9

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I have the ajax script below and in servlet I am trying to read File uploaded but I am getting the below error in servlet

the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
Below is my code

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){

    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST', // GET or POST or PUT or DELETE

    url : "myServlet",
   data:$('#fomr').serialize(),
    contentType:"multipart/form-data",

    success : function(data) {// On Successfull


    },
    error : function(msg) {// When Service call


    }
});

  });
```

Below is the form

```
<form id="fomr" >
 <input name="file1" id="file1"  type="file" accept="image/*" >
 </form>
```

Below is the servlet code

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        try {
            List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
            log.info("Number of fields: " + fields.size() + "<br/><br/>");
            Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();
            if (!it.hasNext()) {
                log.info("No fields found");
                return;
            }
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                FileItem fileItem = it.next();
                boolean isFormField = fileItem.isFormField();
                if (isFormField) {
                    log.info("<td>regular form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() + 
                            "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString()
                            );
                    log.info("</td>");
                } else {
                    log.info("<td>file form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() +
                            "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString() +
                            "<br/>NAME: " + fileItem.getName() +
                            "<br/>CONTENT TYPE: " + fileItem.getContentType() +
                            "<br/>SIZE (BYTES): " + fileItem.getSize() +
                            "<br/>TO STRING: " + fileItem.toString()
                            );
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            log.error("Error {}",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: as far as i know its impossible to get uploaded file through ajax post, but you can also try adding the enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)